# What is the correct suggested edit review resolution (reject) for edits that make grammar worse?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I just reviewed [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5400189), which adds code formatting to things which aren't actually code, rearranges things, and trashes grammar in the process.

(In particular, it changed "This line fails with error (barf): (blah)", a sentence with subject, verb, and abverbial clause, to "If I add this line (blah) fails with (barf)", a mismash with an adverbial clause, no subject, verb, and another adverbial clause)

What's the correct reject reason for "It tries to be helpful (not vandalism) but introduces errors?"

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: No it isn't, the definition of vandalism is *willful or malicious destruction or defacement*  It requires intent to be destructive.

Comment: Interesting. That's not the case in my mothertongue (we can have "involuntary vandalism" here).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it's making the post worse, the edit is not a valid one and therefore an "invalid edit":

> **This edit is incorrect** or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

About the vandalism reason:

> This edit introduces spam, defaces the post in some way, or is otherwise inappropriate.

I believe it wouldn't be the right option here as:

- The edit did not introduce spam.
- The edit did not deface the post near enough to warrant the use of the "vandalism" reason.
- The edit seemed to be made in good faith and did not intentionally make the post worse than it was in my opinion.

The "radical change" reason also wouldn't be appropriate:

> This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.

Although the post made the post's grammar worse, it's fairly clear that the original meaning of the post was not lost.

Comment: I wonder if the system use these reasons for any statistics or if it is just to help the editor...

Comment: That's the reason I used; two other editor reviewers said it changed the meaning too much.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I don't see how the post substantially changed the meaning of the post, I suspect the other reviewers saw a large block of text added and the line break and thought it was their own addition or something.